# Documentation for newer version of Ember Data

Tags: ember-data

It seems like the documentation for Ember Data from v14 doesn't match the beta versions that are coming out now.

Are there any resources that explain how to use the latest versions of Ember Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Ember Data goes 1.0 the documentation on the site is matching the version that was released with 1.0.  You can view the latest documentation here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md